# If $\operatorname{Re}z^n > 0$ for all $n$, then $z$ is real

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'd like a hint, if you can, for this exercise. I tried many ways  but finally I could not solve it. Here it is :

> Let $z$ any complex number for which $\operatorname{Re}(z^n)>0$ for every natural number $n$. Prove that $z$ is a real positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Write $z$ in polar form.

Show that if $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$ is an angle not equal to $0$, there exists some $n$ so that $n \theta$ is in the second or third quadrant.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Convert $z$ into its polar form $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$. If $Re(z^n) > 0$ for all $n$, then $Re(e^{in\theta}) = \cos(n\theta) > 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates, $z^n=r^n\cos(n\theta)+ir^n\sin(n\theta)$. For $\cos(n\theta)$ to remain positive, one must have $\theta=2k\pi$.